# Displace cube into origin with OpenGL

Tags: opengl, graphics, points, glm-math

I'm drawing a bunch of points inside a 64x64x64 cube and can't figure out how to displace the origin so that rotations are done around the center of the cube.
My vertex data is stored inside a 1D array, going from {(0,0,0), (0,0,1), ..., (63, 63, 63)}.

This is my current code to setup the matrices each frame:

```
// Set ProjectionMatrix
projectionMatrix = glm::perspective(90.0f, (GLfloat)width / (GLfloat) height,0.1f, 1000.f);
glUniformMatrix4fv(location_projectionMatrix, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(projectionMatrix));

// Set ModelViewMatrix
glm::mat4 identity = glm::mat4(1.0);
glm::mat4 viewTranslate = glm::translate(identity, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -translate_z));
glm::mat4 viewRotateX   = glm::rotate(viewTranslate, rotate_x, glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
glm::mat4 viewRotateY   = glm::rotate(viewRotateX, rotate_y, glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
modelViewMatrix = viewRotateY;
glUniformMatrix4fv(location_modelViewMatrix, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(modelViewMatrix));
```

I tried to just translate the cube by -32 into the x and y direction, but without success.

Comment: What do you mean by *without success*?

Comment: That the cube is displaced, but not in the way I want it to be. Rotations and zooming should be done related to the center of the cube, currently this origin is one of the corners.

Comment: So translate by half of it's size first.

Comment: As I said...that's what I tried. I just replaced the first two components of the translation vector by -dimensionX/2 and -dimensionY/2. The result was the cube is now placed correctly, but the point of rotation is still the same. I want to rotate around the center of the cube.

Comment: `glm::rotate(viewTranslate,` looks pretty bad to me. Anyway, it should change, so I'd just double-check the code.

Comment: The parameters rotate_x and rotate_y are coming from my motion callback function. Now, what do YOU mean by "pretty bad"?

Comment: maybe http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/16719/what-is-the-correct-order-to-multiply-scale-rotation-and-translation-matrices-f will clarify things for you

Comment: Ok, I still can't figure out how to do it. I've set the camera position to (0,0,10), the lookat point to (-dimx/2, -dimy/2, -translate_z) and the up parameter to (0,1,0), but still no satisfying result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matrix operations are non commutative .It means that doing translation first and then rotation is not the same as doing rotation and then translation.Usually the order is :scale-> rotation -> translation.
So try this instead:

```
glm::mat4 viewRotateX   = glm::rotate(identity, rotate_x, glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
glm::mat4 viewRotateY   = glm::rotate(viewRotateX, rotate_y, glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
glm::mat4 viewTranslate = glm::translate(viewRotateY   , glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -translate_z));
```

Comment: Yeah, forgot about that. Now, I'm able to move the origin inside the center of the cube when I replace the components of the translation vector by (-dimx/2, -dimy/2, -dimz/2). The problem now is how I can use that and still be able to zoom in and out. I don't know where to put the "translate_z" parameter.